# Export from generated API code is not seen by Vite

Tags: javascript, typescript, vite, openapi-generator

I am migrating our frontend to use Vite. We are using the OpenAPI generator Axios client to generate all our API code from a specification.

I have generated the code again, and see it in the target folder. Afterwards, I am building it using npm and a dist folder appears. Then I am adding it as a local import in my package.json file and install it. It's the same as it was before.

```
"restClient": "file:src/api/generated-sources"
```

When I start the Vite dev server, for some reason I am getting below error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/src/api/generated-sources/dist/index.js' does not provide an export named 'SortParams' (at HomeView.vue:6:3)
```

I am using this enum in my code without any errors being shown. Only when running the server it throws an error.

This is the enum, in the generated file:

```
/**
 *
 * @export
 * @enum {string}
 */
export declare enum SortParams {
    CreationDatetime = "CREATION_DATETIME",
    ModificationDatetime = "MODIFICATION_DATETIME",
    Process = "PROCESS",
    Status = "STATUS"
}
```

Above is coming from a file called api.d.ts, which is generated. There's also a javascript file called api.js, which is built so it's a bit hard to read. A cmd+f reveals that the SortParams enum is present there and seems to be exported.

This is how I am importing it in my HomeView:

```
import {
  CaptureCaseSortParams,
  CaptureCaseStatus,
  Configuration,
  DocumentCaptureCasesApi, 
  PaginationData,
  SortOrder,
} from 'restClient';
```

The error is already being thrown at the line of the import.

Does anyone know what this might be?